# unable to download .apk from https

Tags: android, apk

I've developed for my customer an Android application.
I dont want to release it on the Play Strore.

I've hosted it on my client website (asp.net, I've hadded the MIME type apk : application/vnd.android.package-archive). It works like a breeze via http.

The problem is when I try to download the same apk via https : the download doesn't start. I can see it in the notifications, but the progress bar doesn't move. I've tried with the stock browser and Dolphin browser in Android 2.3 and 4.0. It's allways the same issue.

Comment: Is the HTTPS certificate authority accepted by Android?

Comment: Not truly : It's a self signed certificate. When I go to the download page, the browser warns and I've to accept to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rghav asked me, the HTTPS certificat authority isn't accepted by Android. The only solution is to use a certificate provided from a trusted CA.

Comment: Or you can self sign, email the crt to your device and install it there.

Comment: Just realized you may want to distribute this to a lot of devices, in which case this is less feasible. Paying for the trusted SSL is probably correct then.

Answer (score 0):

remove app_data in Request Filtering >Hidden Segments in IIS it works